# Backbone.js initialize function - why do I need it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've recently tried using Backbone, and wanted to ask a basic question. This view is rendering as you'd expect:

```
(function($){

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'div',
el: $('header'), 

initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, 'render'); 

   this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
},


render: function(){
  $(this.el).html("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
}
});

  var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

**My question is, why can't I just do without the initialize function and put this:**

```
(function($){


var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'div',
el: $('header'), 


render: function(){
  $(this.el).html("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
}
});

this.render(); //No html is rendered on the page


var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

I looked in the source code and the initialize function was an empty function by default, which took me be surprise. I sense the answer is quite straight forward, would appreciate the wisdom of a more experienced Backbone.js developer. Thanks!

Comment: You don't always need the initialize function (in your case for example you could just call the render method when you instantiate it), but it is very useful when you need to pass in certain options to your view when you create it or do some setting up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that at the point you are calling `this.render()`, 'this' is referring to the context of the module and not the Backbone View. If you refactor the code to remove the `this.render()` line and add `listView.render()` after the `listView` instance has been created it should resolve the problem.

In summary, in this instance you don't need the `initialize` function.

Comment: Also, by defining an `initialize` function it will get called when the view is first created, read defined, otherwise the extra options you might want set have to be called when creating a new view, ie. `var listView = new ListView({model: SearchModel})`

Comment: Yes, having it removes the need to call render later on and actually makes it self-rendering

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
(function ($) {
    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        el: $('header'),
        render: function () {
            $(this.el).html("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
        }
    });

    var listView = new ListView();
    // Call render on the view instance
    listView.render();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So exactly what I said without an explanation as to why it failed?